# BBOptim equivalent or alternative in Scala

Tags: r, scala, mathematical-optimization

I'm planning on converting some `R` code to `Scala` and came to a function called [BBOptim](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BB/versions/2011.2-2/topics/BBoptim).  It seems to be a wrapper over `SPG` but having little knowledge about mathematics, I don't know what the equivalent code would be in `Scala`.

For example, is it possible to convert the code below to `Scala`?  Or can there be an alternative for this? I'm suspecting the `SpectralProjectedGradient` or `NonLinearMinimizer` in the [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) library could be used.

```
# Use a preset seed so test values are reproducable. 
require("setRNG")
old.seed <- setRNG(list(kind="Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind="Inversion",
    seed=1234))

rosbkext <- function(x){
# Extended Rosenbrock function
n <- length(x)
j <- 2 * (1:(n/2))
jm1 <- j - 1
sum(100 * (x[j] - x[jm1]^2)^2 + (1 - x[jm1])^2)
}

p0 <- rnorm(500)
BBoptim(par=p0, fn=rosbkext)
```

Thanks in advance.

## Edited

I'm restricted on only using the `JVM` so calling `R` from `Scala` is no possible.

Comment: Just as a side note you can always use R within Scala. There are multiple ways to do this including `jvmr`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, this R library is a wrapper for `spg`, which is the Spectral Projected Gradient algorithm.

The [SPG implementation](http://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eegbirgin/tango/codes.php#spg) by the [TANGO project](http://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eegbirgin/tango/) for nonlinear gradient optimization is written in Fortran 77 with interfaces to a number of languages, including Java. All Java libraries work with Scala and thus this should be a suitable solution. This implementation is the focus of several [academic articles](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v060i03/v60i03.pdf) on Spectral Projected Gradients.

You might also check out the Java API for the [Open Optimization Library](http://ool.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: thx for the advice @Hack-R .  I've taken a look at your link for the TANGO project but it seems it only offers `Fortran` , `C`,  `Octave/Matlab` versions.  Am I downloading the wrong source?? I did select `SPG` .

Comment: @tkrhgch Actually it's also for Java and R. Just one moment

Comment: @tkrhgch The paper mentions *"the TANGO Project web page: http://www.ime.usp.br/~egbirgin/tango/) for nonlinear
programming problems, coded in Fortran 77 and with interfaces to R, AMPL, C/C++,
CUTEr, Java, MATLAB, Octave, Python, and TCL."* and it mentions this is literally the exact function that's used in `BBOptim` in R. I definitely see the Java interface for the Algencan method. If you don't see it for SPG offhand I would email the author at the email they provide on their page or ping the discussion group.

Comment: thank you for your kind and descriptive response.  But unfortunately I cannot find the quotes you mentioned in your link. Am I looking at a wrong page? It doesn't mention anything about R or `BBOptim` either. As you mentioned, http://www.ime.usp.br/~egbirgin/tango/ is the webpage??
I looked at the `Algencan` but it also doesn't include Java interface. In the `README` it says `Interfaces with AMPL, C/C++, and CUTEst are included.`  [This](http://www.ime.usp.br/~egbirgin/tango/downloads.php) is the webpage I'm using for downloads. I apologize my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet if you're limited to the JVM, though not the most idiomatic Scala, is to pick a suitable optimization routine from [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html).  The exact one you're using isn't there, but the general solvers work pretty well on most classes of problems I've thrown at them.  You might have to try several different classes of solution to get a decent box contstraint--make a sharp penalty near where your walls are, then restrict the search space to those surfaces if you're near a wall.

Otherwise, it's fairly easy to call R from Scala using [rScala](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rscala/index.html).  That way you don't have to change the algorithm at all.  (But you do have to have R installed.)

Comment: thx @Rex Kerr .  I've been wondering about the **Apache Commons Math** but is it possible for you to point me to a function I could possibly use? Could `org.apache.commons.math4.optim.nonlinear.scalar.gradient` be the closest?  Or does it just depend.  I would like to be able to reproduce the `BBOptim` result as close as possible.

Comment: @tkrhgch - I hesitate to suggest any particular algorithm.  They have a common interface; I would suggest you try several and compare to the results with BBOptim and/or known good values.  (If you don't have known good values, you should start worrying right away!).  If you prefer to try Breeze's optimizer first, no harm in that.

Comment: Thank you @Rex Kerr.  As you mentioned, I'll give the methods a try and compare the results.  Thanks for pointing me to a direction.